# Combining two different events in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to combine two different events into something more compact. This is what's being used so far:

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'editable.click-edit', function(e) {
    if(e.which==13) {
        fns._resetPageEdit(); //enter
    }
});
$(document).click(function() {
    fns._resetPageEdit(); // click anywhere
});
```

Basically if the user presses the <kbd>enter</kbd> key in the specified text box, a reset method fires. If if the user clicks anywhere else, the same method also fires. I find this to be a little messy because if I were to incorporate more options, organizing it would be even more confusing. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @Jack that wouldn't handle the click anywhere on the document but only that one element.

Comment: So do you really have a `<editable></editable>` tag ?

Comment: You could do something like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/nu6Zg/1/**

Comment: This is one of those case when you don't have clean design available.

Comment: @adeneo Yes I do have a tag named like that.

Comment: @dystroy I had a feeling there was no other way to clean this up. I guess writing neatly and commenting is the probably the best way to keep track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing more which can be tidied up in the example, other than removing the anonymous function on the document `click` handler, removing the duplicate selector and shortening the `if` block:

```
$(document)
    .on('keypress', 'editable.click-edit', function(e) {
        e.which == 13 && fns._resetPageEdit();
    })
    .on('click', fns._resetPageEdit)
```

Comment: It's not exactly the same : depends if the context is needed in `_resetPageEdit`

Comment: The last part should be `$.proxy(fns, '_resetPageEdit')`.

Comment: @dystroy true, this assumes the scope of the event trigger is superflous.

Comment: @Jack I think you mean `$.proxy(fns.resetPageEdit, fns)`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's the same thing.

Comment: I agree with this answer apart the `&&` hack which doesn't improve the readability.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this is interesting, I'll see how I can put some of this to use. I guess a little tidying up the code a bit is perhaps the closest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not much you can do to clean this up, and in fact the two events are distinctly different, so you'd want to keep them somewhat separate:

```
// Keep the keypress event trigger local to the input
$('input#someinput').bind('keypress',function(e){
    var keynum = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if( keynum == 13 ) {
      // enter key was pressed
      fns._resetPageEdit();
    }
});

// Handle a click anywhere on the page
$(document).click(function() {
  fns._resetPageEdit();
});
```

Comment: OP had the correct safe way of placing opening braces, you shouldn't change that ([example](http://jsbin.com/paceca/1/edit)).

Comment: Not sure what's unsafe about placing opening braces on a new line, but updated my answer for sake of consistency(?).